# How to pass Command Line Arguments in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

How can I properly pass a Command Line Argument to assign a number to a variable. Below is a simple password generator that I created but cant get the arguments to work when passing them through the terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This script creates a secure password using all available key combinations.

# System arguments aka command line arguments

import secrets , string, os, sys
from sys import argv

chars = string.ascii_letters+string.punctuation+string.digits

argv = one, two

print()
#pwd_length = int(input('Enter the length of the desired password: '))
pwd_length = two
print()
print('[+] ' + 'Your secure password is:')
print()

for n in range(1):
    output = ""
    for i in range(pwd_length):
        next_index = secrets.SystemRandom().randrange(len(chars))
        output = output + chars[next_index]
    print(output)
print()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is wondering how to make a command line arguement, it ended up being simple, here is the solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This script creates a secure password using all available key combinations.

import secrets , string, os, sys
chars = string.ascii_letters+string.punctuation+string.digits
pwd_length = int(sys.argv[1])

print("\n",'[+] ' + 'Your secure password is:',"\n")

for n in range(1):
    output = ""
    for i in range(pwd_length):
        next_index = secrets.SystemRandom().randrange(len(chars))
        output = output + chars[next_index]
    print(output,"\n")
```